# Criei um formulário de contato para enviar diretamente ao meu email. Ele envia, mas não pega as informações dos inputs de texto

Tags: php, formulário

Olá.

Eu criei um formulário de contato em minha página. Junto com este formulário de contato, criei um documento em PHP para que ele envie para o meu email as informações que o usuário digitou nos inputs de texto do formulário de contato. Eu recebo o email, mas não recebo as informações que o usuário digitou. Alguém saberia me dizer o porquê?

Obrigado.

```
<form action="Send2.php" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
<input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" size="20">
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="20">
<br/>
<br/>

<input type="submit" value="Enviar" >

</form>

<?php

$name= $_POST['nome'];
$email= $_POST['email'];

echo $name;
echo $email;
?>

<?php

$to = "gafr1996@gmail.com";
$subject = "Contato Site - ManaSoft";
$message = "Name: ".$name. "<br/> E-mail: ".$email. "<br/>";
$header = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
$header .= "From: $email\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenta assim:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
<form method="POST" action="seuArquivo.php">

<input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" size="20">
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="20">
<br/>
<br/>

<input type="submit" value="Enviar" >

</form>

</body>

<?php

$name= $_POST['nome'];
$email= $_POST['email'];

echo $name;
echo $email;

$to = "ostdor@hotmail.com";
$subject = "Contato Site - ManaSoft";
$message = "Name: ".$name. "<br/> E-mail: ".$email. "<br/>";
$header = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
$header .= "From: $email\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);

?>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

O PHP não popula o POST ou o GET com `enctype="text/plain"`. Os valores do `enctype` podem ser `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (padrão) ou `multipart/form-data` (usado para enviar arquivos).

No seu caso, não precisa especificar o `enctype` que já será o tipo padrão (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`):

```
<form action="Send2.php" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

O parâmetro action da tag `<form>` só pode conter uma URL relativa `action="meu-ficheiro-local.php"` ou uma URL absoluta  `action="http://www.exemplo.com/exemplo.php"`.
Neste caso o que me está a parecer é que a declaração em php está no mesmo ficheiro que o `<form>`, mas por sua vez o formulário envia o seu conteúdo para o ficheiro **Send2.php**. `<form action="Send2.php" method="post">`

Na minha opinião o melhor a fazer neste caso é usar a variável de servidor `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]`, que retorna o nome do ficheiro que está actualmente em execução. Devemos usar esta variável global dentro do método `htmlspecialchars()` para evitar a exploração das suas vulnerabilidades, abaixo fica um exemplo da implementação.

`<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" >`

Outra questão é o uso de uma estrutura de controlo, pois desta maneira o script irá enviar dois emails, um quando for iniciado e outro quando o formulário for submetido. Para fixar isto podemos nos servir de outra variável de servidor `$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]`que nos devolve o tipo de método com que o ficheiro foi solicitado, os dois métodos mais utilizados são o `GET` e o `POST`, abaixo deixo um exemplo de como ficaria a estrutura.

```
<?php

    //Só envia o email caso o tipo da requisição seja do tipo `POST`  
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

      $name= $_POST['nome'];
      $email= $_POST['email'];

      echo $name;
      echo $email;

      $to = "ostdor@hotmail.com";
      $subject = "Contato Site - ManaSoft";
      $message = "Name: ".$name. "<br/> E-mail: ".$email. "<br/>";
      $header = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
      $header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
      $header .= "From: $email\n";

      mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);
    }
?>
```